# Check available space in a socket write buffer Java

Tags: java, sockets, output

Is a way to check how much space is available in a socket write buffer?

I found that I can check the total size of the buffer with getSendBufferSize() but I couldn't find a way to check how much space is available in the buffer.

Comment: If you find a way to get this value, what are you going to do with it?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if I can guarantee that I can write a message of a certain size within a given time. In nio, as far as I understand, I can write with a timeout, but if the timeout has passed there is a possibility that the data has only been partially written.

Comment: There is no API to return the send buffer space, and there is no write timeout either.

Comment: @EJP Quoting you: "There is no 'write timeout' for a Socket or SocketChannel, but you can get the effect by using a Selector with OP_WRITE and a timeout."

Comment: Anyway, tough luck... (for me)

Comment: @traveh Correct. No actual API for it though.